# how to use <p:ajax> inside <p:tree> of primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using  `<p:tree>`. and trying to use `<p:ajax>` to detect the node selected and excecute action. This is my actual JSF code:

```
<p:tree id="treeDot" value="#{beanRequest.rootDot}" var="node"  selectionMode="single"
    nodeSelectListener="#{beanRequest.clt}" >
    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{beanRequest.clientSelected}" />
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

The server side method:

```
//...
private Client clt;
public void clientSelected(NodeSelectEvent event) {
    //...
}
//...
```

I get the following exception :

```
8 oct. 2012 17:30:01 com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
INFO: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.findTreeNode(UITree.java:111)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.setRowKey(UITree.java:78)
    at org.primefaces.component.tree.TreeRenderer.decodeSelection(TreeRenderer.java:62)
    at org.primefaces.component.tree.TreeRenderer.decode(TreeRenderer.java:38)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:787)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.processDecodes(UITree.java:170)
    at org.primefaces.component.tree.Tree.processDecodes(Tree.java:366)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:506
)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.visitTree(UITree.java:392)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView.visitTree(TabView.java:400)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake.
just replace `nodeSelectListener="#{beanRequest.clt}"` by 
`selection="#{beanRequest.selectedNode}"` 
and create the `selecttedNode` variable in the `beanRequest` like this
 `private TreeNode selectedNode;`

Comment: Which version of Primefaces were you using?

Comment: @Ghasfarost I am using 3.4.2